# Checking for parameters for CLLocationCoordinate2DMake

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mkmapview

I have a mapview where I want to check if latitude og longitude values are empty/nil or not, but either the app crashes, or Xcode is complaining about optional types and what not.

This is my current code, but I want to find out what the best way to get correct format for latitude and longitude coordinates:

```
if let latitude = detailItem!["lat"] as? Double {
    if let longitude = detailItem!["lon"] as? Double {

        // Get location
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        // Set region
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 2000, 2000)
        mapCell.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)

        // Add pin to map
        let marker = MKPointAnnotation()
        marker.coordinate = location
        marker.title = String(detailItem!["name"]!)
        mapCell.mapView.addAnnotation(marker)
    }
}
```

This crashes entries with values.

Comment: "This crashes entries with values." What does that mean? What line crashes, and with what error code?

Comment: Latitude values range from -90 to 90. Longitude values range from -180 to 180. You need to range-check values that you get from a server. If they are out of range they won't work. (I wouldn't expect invalid values to crash however.) I also see that you have a `!` force-unwrap. Don't do that. If detailItem doesn't exist, or it doesn't have a "name" key/value pair, you will crash.